# is there cross platform library to call/create process in c++

Tags: c++, cross-platform

Is there any cross platform library to create process's (using createProcess win32 api in windows for example).
for linux/windows/mac?

Comment: Not sure why you need a whole library for this. Does your compiler not support `#ifdef`?

Comment: dont want to deal with win32 api , already did it once its crap

Comment: There is an ongoing proposal to add std::process to the c++ std library: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1750r1.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [Boost.Process](http://www.boost.org/libs/process/) will do that
2. as will [PoCo](https://pocoproject.org/docs/) (Processes namespace, in Foundation)

None of these are intrusive libraries, and none of these imply UI frameworks. Both will support static linkage without major size overhead.

Comment: You can add that boost::process have been reviewed and refused because it needs some changes of the implementation( but still works ). That's important because if a version of boost::process does get into boost (voted for inclusion), it will not have the same interface than the current implementation.

Comment: @user63898: It says so right there: "Processes namespace, in Foundation" (Foundation _library_ that is). Unfortunately the frames setup of their documentation makes it hard to link directly to that page in a useful manner. [Here is an attempt (link)](http://pocoproject.org/docs/package-Foundation.Processes-index.html), but see the link in the answer for full reference.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, but boost::process is not header only; it uses boost::filesystem which requires pre-built libs...

Answer (score 7):

You could use Qt which implements many OS utilities in a platform-independent way, eg. processes, threads, networking, GUI of course,....

Comment: yeah i love it but its to big for me to include

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at https://github.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library, a modern C++(11) platform independent process library without external dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run notepad using:
std::system("notepad.exe");
I beleive in linux it also should work.

Answer (score 0):

[wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) also contains a cross-platform process control library for spawning child processes through the `wxProcess` class.  If cross-platform threading is needed, it can be handled through the `wxThread` class as well.  Overall, wxWidgets a nice cross-platform library that's fairly light-weight and pretty straight-forward to use.  You can find some great getting-started tutorials on the main website that show you how to get an application up and running.