# Create subprocess and get live output from it. (Crossplatform solutions welcomed)

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous

I need to create pipe/subprocess and get output from it as it will change and pass it as string to main process. It would be great if there is some crossplatform solution to it (but right now windows is main priority)

I tried Observer pattern plus Async from std (I don't think that it's working right).

All in C++ and WinApi (if needed)

Code:

```
void pipe::Pipe::syncMode()
{
    //some code for subproccessing in Windows
}

void pipe::Pipe::asyncMode() {
    std::async(std::launch::async, &pipe::Pipe::syncMode, this);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017399/is-there-cross-platform-library-to-call-create-process-in-c

Comment: @JesperJuhl I kinda partly solved it by using Async, but now had some problems with getting output.

Answer (score 0):

[CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), if you prioritize Windows. 
Can get you:
1. Standard Output and error from the child process.
2. Return code of the child process.
3. Can set security attributes.
4. Can inherit handles from parent process. And a lot more.

If you needed a cross platform solution, [popen](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html) is your way to go.
popen is not as sophisticated as createprocess. But if you only want to invoke a child process and get its standard output, it is more than enough.

Sample popen code to create a process and get its standard output

```
std::wstring ExecuteCmdLine(std::string cmd)  // NOLINT
//! Execute given comment in std::string and returns output as std::wstring
{
    try
    {
        printf("@@@@@ \t Inside CMcUtil::executeCMDLine \t @@@@@\n");
        printf("The commnad to execute is : \"%s\"\n", cmd.c_str());
        wchar_t buffer[128];
        ATL::CStringW result = "";
        FILE* pipe = _wpopen(CA2W(cmd.c_str()), L"r");
        if (!pipe)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
        }
        try
        {
            while (!feof(pipe)) {
                if (fgetws(buffer, 128, pipe) != nullptr)
                    result += buffer;
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            _pclose(pipe);
            throw;
        }
        _pclose(pipe);
        return result.GetBuffer();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ERRMSG("Exception caught while executing command in command prompt\n");
        return L"Error";
    }
}
```